# Не могу понять как мне переопределить класс dict и его метод get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы

Мне нужно реализовать класс `MyDict`, который будет вести себя точно также, как и обычный словарь, за исключением того, что метод `get` по умолчанию будет возвращать не **`None`**, а число **`0`**.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 0


mydict = MyDict()
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

Дальше я в ступоре, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну `mydict = MyDict()` создает инстанс вашего класса, а `mydict = {...}` создает оригинальный dict и про ваш класс ничего не знает, а значит не выйдет использовать синтаксис `mydict = {...}` (ну если не лезть в манкипатчинг, но это все сломает). Также вместо `__get__` нужно переопределять `__getitem__` для `mydict['aaa']`, а метод `get` просто переопределить

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ это переопределить метод `get`:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return super().get(key, 0)

d = MyDict({"a": 1, "b": 2})
print(d.get("a"))
print(d.get("c"))
```

Вывод:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

    def get(self, key):
        return self.__getitem__(key)
```

Метод `__missing__` будет вызван, если `__getitem__` не найдёт нужный элемент.
Как написал [vitidev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191496/vitidev), вам нужно по-другому передавать элементы. У вас просто `mydict` начинает ссылаться на обычный словарь.
Заполнять его нужно так

```
mydict.update({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4})
```

Comment: Спасибо вам:  mydict = MyDict({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4})  print(mydict.get('set')) работает)

Comment: У этого решения есть нежелательный побочный эффект, `mydict[key]` не будет бросать исключение для несуществующего ключа, а по условию задачи метод должен вести себя как в `dict`, т.е. бросать исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, создать класс на основе встроенного словаря, и переопределить метод `get` с аргументом `default`, равным `0`. Затем вызвать метод `get` встроенного словаря.

Нечто подобное предлагали [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1398857), но в той реализации нет возможности указать методу `mydict.get` аргумент `default`, отличный от нуля (это не возымеет действия)

```
class mydict(dict):
    def get(self, key, default=0):
        return dict.get(self, key, default)
```